# Compare two char arrays of hashbytes function

Tags: sql

In SQL Server 2014 express I have a trigger that in the middle runs this:

```
    SELECT @hb = HASHBYTES('MD5',CAST(Document AS varbinary(8000))) FROM Documents
    SELECT @ha = HASHBYTES('MD5',CAST(Document AS varbinary(8000))) FROM inserted
    IF @ha=@hb
        SELECT @dg=null
    ELSE
        SELECT @dg=Document FROM inserted
```

But when I insert the values I got always `@dg` set to null.
Where is the mistake?

Comment: Any whitespace hanging out in one of those two `document` values that a `TRIM()` might clear up? Can you have it spit out the two MD5'd values and check them out manually? Something seems fishy.

Comment: The problem is I can't debug it because I'm using express edition. But I know that ´@hb´ has a value and ´@ha´ has a value. And I know that ´Document´ from inserted and from ´Documents´ must be different. I know because once I insert I check it using *SELECT* and *CAST* and the hash is different...